# What does 'Acme' stand for in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony

The standard bundle in Symfony2 is 'Acme', but what does that stand for?

Comment: If you follow the introductory tutorial, it should become more clear: [The Big Picture](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html).

Comment: @hakre the link is broken... If anyone finds a replacing one, please post it here.

Comment: @Al.G.: See here the archived copy: http://web.archive.org/web/20110404124741/http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html - it has been updated for more recent version (was for 2.0).

Comment: @hakre Well I found the same page for the current version - http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html

Answer (score 78, accepted):

ACME (A Company (that) Makes Everything) is a fictional company from the Looney Tunes: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation

It's used as a [placeholder name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name) (like "foo", "bar", etc).

[image]

Comment: A heartwarming conversation about watching cartoons has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246748/discussion-on-answer-by-epoc-what-does-acme-stand-for-in-symfony2).

Answer (score 21):

It means "A Company (that) Makes Everything"

Answer (score 6):

*ACME* is the root namespace name of these standard bundles. Code therein you should identify as the code you write your own, so not the code of the framework itself which you should not touch.

You find the usage of that namespace outlined in the introductory chapter [The Big Picture](http://web.archive.org/web/20121030234427/http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) (archived copy).

It's used exemplary, it hints being the name of *your company*, see [Acme Corporation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_Corporation) on wikipedia for some cultural references.

But sure, Symfony2 is neither a computer game nor a fictional movie, so probably it's hard to draw that connection line.

*See Also:* **[[Newbie] Why ACME prefix? (symfony framework forum)](http://forum.symfony-project.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=35419)** (21 May 2011)

Answer (score 0):

ACME is a simple fun way to either suggests that it is "A Company (that) Makes Everything" instead of a company that's named as `foo` or `baz`. While it does have something to do with the Cartoons, the term has had a [great trend of search](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=acme) since the beginning of Google Trends.